# Why does my Axios Response return a 404 even though I am setting the mock response?

Tags: reactjs, axios, storybook

I am trying to mock my REST requests for a react/ts project when testing in Storybook using Axios. Even though I am setting the response to an array object, it still seems to be responding with a "Request failed with status code 404" status.

Here is my component making the REST call: **TestPrompt.tsx**

```
const onClickHandler = () => {
    requestOrMock("http://localhost:9002/projectPlan/projectTasks?project=FAKEWID")
}
```

Here is the method my **TestPrompt** component is using to make the request: **UtilityFunctions.ts**

```
import  axios from 'axios';

export const axiosMock = axios.create();

export const requestOrMock = async (uri: string) => {
    const response = axiosMock.get(uri);
    return response;
}
```

Here is my test that is mocking the response: **Prompt.stories.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import {storiesOf} from '@storybook/react';
import  TestPrompt  from "../components/common/Prompt";
import  MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import { axiosMock } from "../utils/utilityFunctions";

const mock = new MockAdapter(axiosMock);

const blankPromptRequestUri = "http://localhost:9002/projectPlan/projectTasks?project=FAKEWID";

const footballTeams = [
    {
        "descriptor": "New England Patriots",
        "id": "NewEnglandPatriots"
    },
    {
        "descriptor": "Seattle Seahawks",
        "id": "SeattleSeahawks"
    }
];

storiesOf('Components/MultiSelect', module)
  .add('Prompt1', () => {
    mock.onGet(blankPromptRequestUri).reply(200, footballTeams);
    return (
      <TestPrompt/>
    );
  })
```

When I click on this component in storybook, it sends out the request to the designated url, but it gets the 404 response rather than the footballTeams object I have specified. Any idea what I have done wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your problem correctly, you need to call onGet() of mock to setup the mock end point and then send a request to that end point.

```
mock.onGet("/teams").reply(200, footballTeams);

storiesOf('Components/MultiSelect', module)
  .add('Prompt1', () => {
    axios.get("/teams")
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    return (
      <TestPrompt/>
    );
  })
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the question, but the request to that end point is being sent when I click on the component in Storybook, and that is when I am seeing the 404 rather than the footballTeams response. Question updated.

Comment: Did your try removing the host (localhost:9002) just keeping the routes?

Answer (score 0):

The requests that were being made were being made relative to the host, so rather than "http://localhost:9002/projectPlan/projectTasks?project=FAKEWID" being sent, it was actually "/projectPlan/projectTasks?project=FAKEWID". It is likely that you will only need to pass in the routes here.